# Some Contacts not appearing in "Select Contacts" tool for Shared Activities

Tags: contact, activities, search, shared-activities

Some of my users are complaining about certain contacts not showing up in the Contact search when Shared Activities is enabled.

The one contact I can reliably duplicate this bug with is a contact without a first name.  Is that a known bug?  Is there something else that would cause this?

Comment: Success ticket here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D8pyAAC